# inserting a new element in a binary search tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to insert a new element in a binary search tree, i wrote the following function, but it does not seem to work and i cant seem to understand why.

code:

```
node* new_node(int data)
{
    node* ptr=new node();
    ptr->data=data;
    ptr->left=NULL;
    ptr->right=NULL;
    return ptr;
}
void insert(node* root,int d)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        root=new_node(d);
    else if(d<root->data)
        insert(root->left,d);
    else
        insert(root->right,d);
}
```

Comment: `root=new_node(d);` modifies the local `root` parameter.  It does not modify the argument the caller passed to the `insert` routine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead-

```
node* insert(node* root,int d)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        root = new_node(d);
    else if(d<root->data)
        root->left = insert(root->left,d);
    else
        root->right = insert(root->right,d);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for adding children. Should be `root->left = insert(root->left,d);` and `root->right = insert(root->right,d);`

Comment: thanks for identifying my mistake. Corrected it. :)

Answer (score 4):

When you pass an object to a function, the function receives a copy of the value as a parameter. Modifying a copy of a value has no effect on the original object (at least in case of fundamental types like pointers. This doesn't apply to "referential" classes that have internal indirection).

In order to modify an object that is outside of the function, you need to use indirection. You already have a layer of indirection since you pass a pointer. By indirecting through the pointer argument, you can modify the node that is outside the function. But assigning the pointer is not an attempt of modifying the pointed node. It is an attempt at modifying the pointer. But the pointer is a copy, so the assignment has no effect to the outside of the function.

So, you need a second layer of indirection: Pass a reference to the pointer, so that assigning the pointer modifies the referred pointer instead of a copy. Another approach is to use a return value, as demonstrated by [Abdullah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59649052/2079303). Note that this changes how the function should be called slightly.